# How to upload PDF file on parse server (parse.com)

Tags: file, pdf, parse-platform, upload, parse-server

I know how to upload image file.I upload image as base 64 string.How to upload other formats like pdf,doc etc.Any idea.

Comment: Are you on iOS, Android, Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

You upload them the same way but with different content type.

For example for a PDF file in iOS SDK:

```
let file = PFFile(name: "file.pdf", data: fileData, contentType: "application/pdf")
```

[Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=content%20types%20files) for `content type` of your file type that you want to upload.